# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'vibrate' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-cli, capacitor

good afternoon, i'm sorry by my bad english, i have a problem with ionic capacitor, i'm trying use the plugin Vibration, the documentation don't describe much things, but i 'm getting from terminal of android studio this message

Error:

[image]

this is my code:

```
import { Plugins, CameraResultType } from '@capacitor/core';
import { Vibration } from '@ionic-native/vibration/ngx';

const { Camera } = Plugins

interface Props extends React.Props<ControlVibratorComponent> {

}

export default class ControlVibratorComponent extends React.Component<Props>{

    constructor(props: any, private vibration: Vibration) {
        super(props);
    }

    changeNotificationState(e: any) {
        if (e.detail.value > 0) {
            console.log('vibrando');
            // this.vibration.vibrate([2000, 1000, 2000]);
            // console.log(this.vibration);
            this.vibration.vibrate(2000);
        } else {
            console.log('stop');
            this.vibration.vibrate(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are building your app using Capacitor, it is better to use capacitor plugins wherever possible.
For vibration, you can use capacitor [Haptics Plugin](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/haptics/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Cordova plugins work with the Capacitor. But if it does, the steps to use this plugin are:

1- Add the plugin:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-vibration
```

2- Install the package:

```
npm install @ionic-native/vibration
```

3- Import it in app.module.ts and add it in providers:

```
import {YourPlugin} from './path-to-your-plugin-in-node_modules';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ...
    YourPlugin
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Import it in your component controller (.page.ts file) and make an instance of it in the constructor and use its methods:

```
import {YourPlugin} from './path-to-your-plugin-in-node_modules';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-somepage',
  templateUrl: './somepage.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./somepage.page.scss'],
})
export class SomepagePage implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private plugin: YourPlugin) {
  }
}
```

If you did anything else you made a mistake. do it this way again.